# How do I configure Multi-Seat on CentOS 6.2?

Tags: linux, centos, multiseat, xephyr

I am trying to set up a CentOS 6.2 installation to allow running it optionally in a multi-seat configuration. It normally runs as dual-head, but I would like to have the option to use the second keyboard and mouse with the second screen as independent terminal.

I tried using Xephyr but I failed to find a way to separate the keyboard events. For example when trying to run something like this:

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1280x1024 -br -keybd evdev,,device=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000\:00\:1a.0-usb-0\:1.1\:1.0-event-kbd,xkbmodel=evdev,xkblayout=us -reset -terminate :1
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Couldn't find keyboard driver evdev
```

A package xorg-x11-drv-evdev-2.6.0-2.el6.x86_64 is installed.

Alternatively I would consider starting new sessions from the display manager (or even via different runlevels), but given the lack of an /etc/Xorg.conf I don't know how to apply the documentation I can find on the net (which seems to be mostly 4-6 years old).

How can I set up multi-seat CentOS? Is there some documentation I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up multiseat on CentOS 6.2 by using the xephyr 1.7.6-4 package from Fedora-12.

It already has support of evdev driver and works on CentOS.